# How do I dynamically add a Dijit widget to a Dojo form?

Tags: forms, post, widget, dojo

I'm trying to add a new FilteringSelect widget dynamically to a preexisting form I made out of declarative tags (on page load).

```
prereqs = 0;
function addAnotherPrerequisite(){  

    var newPreReqCursor = dijit.byId("Prerequisite"+(prereqs-1)).domNode;
    dojo.create("input",{
        id:"prerequisite"+prereqs,
        jsId:"Prerequisite"+prereqs,                        
        dojoType:"dijit.form.FilteringSelect",
        store:"PrerequisitesStore",
        searchAttr:"name",
        style:"width: 350px;",
        required:"true",
        class: "appendedPreReq"},newPreReqCursor,"after");


    dojo.parser.parse( newPreReqCursor.parentNode ); 

    prereqs++;
}
```

This code properly builds a FilteringSelect widget, but the widget does not seem to be registered with the form. Whenever I submit the form, none of the values in the new widgets appear. The validation attribute works, though, and it properly pulls the values from the store.I can even call the new widget via its jsId(Prerequisite1, Prerequisite2, etc) It just won't POST!

Instead of dojo.create I also tried called the FilteringSelect widget directly. This also made the widget, but did not register the values with the form during POSTing.

```
var filteringSelect = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
        id: "prereq"+prereqs,
        jsId: "Prerequisite"+prereqs,
        store: PrerequisitesStore,
        searchAttr: "name",
        required: true,
        style: 'width: 350px;',
        class: 'appendedPreReq'
    },
    "prerequisite"+prereqs).startup();
```

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like there's some sort of bug or something. I had to define the 'name' attribute explicitly to get the widget to show up in my form's .getDependents() method. That's how dijit.forms gets its list of form values. After doing this I also couldn't access this widget by dijit.byId (didn't return anything, silently caught the error I guess), so I returned the object via its jsId with an eval.

```
prereqs = 0;
function(){
    var newPreReqCursor = eval("Prerequisite"+(prereqs-1));
    newPreReqCursor = newPreReqCursor.domNode;

    dojo.create("input",{
            id:"Prerequisite"+prereqs,
            name:"Prerequisite"+prereqs,
            jsId:"Prerequisite"+prereqs,
            dojoType:"dijit.form.FilteringSelect",
            store:"PrerequisitesStore",
            searchAttr:"name",
            style:"width: 350px;",
            required:"true",
            class: "appendedPreReq"},newPreReqCursor,"after");

    var filterSelect = dojo.parser.parse( newPreReqCursor.parentNode );
}
```

Comment: This was helpful. I found that all that was required was specifying the name in my situation: `new dijit.form.TextBox({name: inputNode.name}, inputNode);`

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. Just create a new object like that:

```
// first let's create an empty node (you can reuse the existing one)
var node = dojo.create("div", {
  // all necessary node attributes
  className: "appendedPreReq",
  style: {
    width: "350px"
  }
}, "myAnchorNodeId", "after");

// now let's create a widget
var widget = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect(
  {
    // all necessary widget properties
    id: "prereq" + prereqs,
    store: PrerequisitesStore,
    searchAttr: "name",
    required: true
  },
  node // optional node to replace with the widget
);
```

Read all about it:

- http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/info
- http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/FilteringSelect

Comment: That was my initial intention. I didn't include the dojo.create script from my attempt at instantiating dijit.form.FilteringSelect.

I've actually answered my own question (looks like a bug). Thanks for the help ,though. :D

Answer (score 0):

yes while creating widgets as said by Eugene Lazutkin the input type hidden related with the filtering select gets the name as of the id, and also the value of the hidden field is updating correctly. But when the filtering select is created thr .create() method we need to give the name , and also the value of the hidden field is not updating after we select some values from the filtering select(even when we blur out). Eugene Lazutkin can you let me know why its happening so... how to update the value of hidden field in the .create() method.